# Splitting empty string with space as a separator returns ['']

Tags: python

Is this a correct behaviour?

```
>>> ''.split(' ')
['']
```

Shouldn't it be an empty array? I mean, there are no spaces in an empty string so there is nothing to split, it should be [], no?

When I use a None as separator, it is empty array:

```
>>> ''.split()
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has already explained this behavior

> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example,
>   '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']). The sep argument may
>   consist of multiple characters (for example, '1<>2<>3'.split('<>')
>   returns ['1', '2', '3']). Splitting an empty string with a specified
>   separator returns [''].
>
> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a
>   single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the
>   start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.
>   Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just
>   whitespace with a None separator returns [].

Comment: Hmm. Strage. I was just reading this piece of documentation several times and I missed that sentence: "Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns ['']."

Comment: @RichardKnop Surely it's strange...

Answer (score 1):

[Python docs explicitly specify this behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns [''].